# Extract Data from a Data frame with a given condition

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a Dataframe name `df_mtrs`:

[image]

I want to extract data from the data frame where `customer_name` presents in `trxyear` (2019 to 2022) continuously.

```
trxyear => Years e.g. 2019 
customer_name => Company name e.g. ABC.ltd
Total_meters => meters(cloths) 20.0 meters
```

***Does anyone think this question has already answer somewhere just send a link then I will gladly close this question.***

Comment: Use [df.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using `query()` and `isin()`

```
import pandas as pd

data = [["2019", "Customer1", 20.0],
        ["2020", "Customer1", 25.0],
        ["2021", "Customer1", 27.5],
        ["2019", "Customer2", 10.0],
        ["2020", "Customer2", 50.0],
        ["2021", "Customer2", 70.0],
        ["2019", "Customer3", 20.0],
        ["2020", "Customer3", 50.0],
        ["2021", "Customer3", 40.0],
        ["2022", "Customer3", 210.0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["trxyear", "customer_name", "Total_meters"])

# You can customize the filtering criteria
years_filter = ["2019", "2020", "2021", "2022"]
customer_filter = ["Customer2"]

# This returns the df with the filtered entries that match your criteria
df_filtered = df.query("trxyear in @years_filter and customer_name in @customer_filter")
# Sum up all the meters across the years you are searching for - if you plan on searching by multiple customer_name values, you would have to group_by customer_name
total_meters = df_filtered["Total_meters"].sum()

print(df_filtered)
print (f"Total meters: {total_meters}")
```

Assuming that the `trxyear` column is of type int, you can also run the following query with a continuous range for the year criteria:

```
df_filtered = df.query(f"trxyear >={start_year} and trxyear <={end_year} and customer_name in @customer_filter")
```